# Cannot read json file properly

Tags: python, json

I want to read json file from online https://api.myjson.com/bins/y2k4y and print based on the parameter like 'ipv4', 'ipv6'. I have written code in python. It is showing me this error. Please advise me to solve this problem.

**Python code**

```
import requests
import json

# Method To Get REST Data In JSON Format
def getResponse(url,choice):

    response = requests.get(url)

    if(response.ok):
        jData = json.loads(response.content)
        if(choice=="deviceInfo"):
            print("working")
            deviceInformation(jData)
    else:
        print("NOT working")
        response.raise_for_status()


# Parses JSON Data To Find Switch Connected To H4
def deviceInformation(data):
    global switch
    global deviceMAC
    global hostPorts
    switchDPID = ""
    print ( data)
    for i in data:
        print ("i: ", i['ipv4'])


deviceInfo = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/y2k4y"
getResponse(deviceInfo,"deviceInfo")
```

**Error**

```
  File "E:/aaa/e.py", line 27, in deviceInformation
    print ("i: ", i['ipv4'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

**json file**
https://api.myjson.com/bins/y2k4y

Answer (score 1):

`jData` is a `dict` with only 1 key `devices`. `devices` contain all the other info which you require.

Change `for i in data` to `for i in data['devices']`:

```
for i in data['devices']:
        print ("i: ", i['ipv4'])
        print ("i: ", i['ipv6'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `for i in data['devices']:` instead of `for i in data:`